# How could one find the line by line instructions that built-in commands follow when executing

Tags: p5.js

I'm playing around with vertices and `beginShape()` to get a feel for it and understand how the function works. I used the p5.js website's reference page as a guide.

While doing that, I wrote this code which gave me an unexpected result:

```
  stroke('red')
  strokeWeight(5)

 beginShape(POINTS);
  vertex(25, 25); // top left
  stroke('yellow')
  vertex(25, 75); // top right
  push()
  stroke('green')
  strokeWeight(25)
  vertex(75, 75); // bottom right
  pop()
  push()
  strokeWeight(25)
  vertex(75, 25); // bottom left
  pop()
 endShape();
```

RESULT I EXPECTED:

```
top left: color = red, size = 5
top right: color = yellow, size = 5
bottom right: color = green, size = 25
bottom left: color = yellow, size = 25
```

RESULT I GOT:

```
top left: color = red, size = 5
top right: color = yellow, size = 5
bottom right: color = green, size = 5
bottom left: color = red, size = 5
```

**SUMMARY:**

I couldn't figure out why I got the result I got, and playing with the code made the results even more confusing, I came to a conclusion that I just don't know what happens within the computer when
`beginShape()` is called.

I'm looking for an in depth explanation for what the computer does when `beginShape()` is called. (By explanation I mean like the way Dan Shiffman from the YouTube channel "Coding Train" explains that when `mousePressed()` is called the computer stops running `draw()` and executes the `mousePressed()` function. Another example would be: Dan Shiffman also explains that first of all `setup()` runs first when executing the program and only then `draw()` loops.

**QUESTIONS:**

1. I want to understand what happens within the program when I call `beginShape()`. This kind of information is not given in the p5 reference page. (a different phrasing for the question could be: *how does the program execute the function `beginShape()`.*)
2. I want to know what this type of *'behind the scenes'* information about the language/library is called so I could find it more easily in the future, for p5 and for other languages too.

Comment: Are you sure you posted the correct code? Or that what you listed in expected results/returned results is correct? (Btw. It would be easier if you separated out the bits that work fine from the bits that don't, those 8 lines are hard to read.) With the code you provided, I'm getting back points with stroke weight 5, and colours: red, yellow, green, yellow.

Comment: Btw. I made sure to end all lines of code with semicolons and would recommend you do the same. Though that's not the reason why I'm getting your expected colours back, it's the same with your original code.